# Is it safe to keep using django web app on local server and how safe is my data if I do it that

Tags: python, django, sqlite, localhost

This might seem like a stupid question, but is it okay to keep using a django based web app on localhost. The abstract is that I made a accounting web app that I would like to use for my daily business transactions, I don't want to deploy the web app on internet. Is it okay to keep using it on local server with sqlite3 or is there another method of achieving the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything is hosted locally, I think your data should be fine.